# Is it possible to generate .pages documents in a .NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to generate .pages documents for Macs from a .NET web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in .net without a third party solution. Since it's a web app, you could just connect to an existing API from within your application to do this, instead of finding, or making your own library for .net.

[Google Docs and Cloud Converter service](https://cloudconvert.com/apiconsole) is an option for this conversion and [there is a wrapper for this API usable in .NET on github](https://github.com/aliencube/CloudConvert.NET). Once you've installed the wrapper you can use a simple execution like this (with output being `.pages` document). From the documentation:

```
// Convert asynchronously
var response = await wrapper.ConvertAsync(input, output, conversion);

// Convert synchronously
var response = wrapper.ConvertAsync(input, output, conversion).Result;
```

Now the `input` would have to be one of the [supported file types](https://cloudconvert.com/formats) from the API, but there is a lot of flexibility there and you can certainly get a .pages file in your `response`.
This would mean that another file would need to be "generated" first, so it isn't a *direct* generation from .NET. The advantage here is that it's relatively simple to set-up, and because the conversion happens off of your server that might help performance. But the downside is that it is an external solution and, with using any API, be sure you have done due diligence on the business and security needs of these documents you are generating with this service.

While there is no native .NET solution, and, since you are from within a web app, Google's Cloud Convert API could be a good work-around for you to generate .pages.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, the Cloud Convert API will be very useful for the client organization, which uses the Google ecosystem